# Expected exit time from state i

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

In a Markov chain, if I want to find mean exit time, is it better to think about it as the opposite of mean recurrence time or related to expected first passage?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_{ij}=\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_n=i)$ be the transition probabilities, and define $$\tau = \inf\{n>0: X_n\ne i\mid X_0=i\}.$$
Then for each positive integer $k$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(\tau=k) &= \mathbb P\left(\{X_k\ne i\}\bigcap\cap_{j=1}^{k-1}\{X_j=i\}\mid X_0=i \right)\\
&= \mathbb P(X_k\ne i\mid X_{k-1}=i )\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \mathbb P(X_j=i\mid X_{j-1}=i)\\
&= (1-p_{ii})p_{ii}^{k-1},
\end{align}
so that $\tau\sim\mathrm{Geo}(1-p_{ii})$. It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[\tau] &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\mathbb P(\tau=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p_{ii})p_{ii}^{k-1}\\
&= (1-p_{ii})\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)p_{ii}^k\\
&= \frac1{1-p_{ii}}.
\end{align}